# When is a linear combination of two matrices invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question appeared in some work I'm doing at the moment. I don't need the answer, it just interested me.

Let $A$ be an invertible $n\times n$ matrix, and let $B$ be another $n\times n$ matrix, both over some field $k$. I guess $k$ should be algebraically closed, just so I can split polynomials. Let $\lambda\in k$. We are interested in the matrix
$$ A+\lambda B,$$
and in particular whether it is invertible.

Treating $\lambda$ as a variable, it's clear that $f(\lambda)=\det(A+\lambda B)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$. Since $f(0)\neq 0$, $f$ is not the zero polynomial, and therefore there are at most $n$ values of $\lambda$ for which $A+\lambda B$ is non-invertible. In fact, it is easy to see that there are at most $\mathrm{rank}(B)$ such values by change of basis. It is not hard to give constructions that show that all values between $0$ and $\mathrm{rank}(B)$ can occur.

My interaction with this problem comes from bilinear forms, where an alternating form on a vector space was a linear combination of two, one of rank $56$ and the other of rank $12$. Because my form came from points on a $1$-dimensional torus, I knew that there was exactly one value of $\lambda$ which yielded a form with a radical, i.e., a non-invertible matrix.

I came to the conclusion that $B$ in this case must be very special. In particular, I guessed that the collection of all $B$ such that $f(\lambda)$ does not have $n$ distinct roots is small, probably Zariski closed.

So my questions are:

**Is this true?**

and

**Is this obviously true or false?**

My third, softer, question, is

**Is this sort of thing well-known/previously looked at?**

Of course one obvious case where it is looked at is where $B=-I_n$, as this is the characteristic polynomial! If it is looked at more generally, my guesses would be in analysis, if $k=\mathbb{R}$, or perturbation theory for small $\lambda$.

(For $A=I_n$ the answer is clear, as it is all matrices $B$ with distinct eigenvalues.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question of whether $A + \lambda B$ is invertible is known as the [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem). It is indeed well studied.

To your first two questions: the answer is yes. Note that in the "generic case", $B$ is invertible, which means that
$$
\det(A + \lambda B) = \det(B)\det(AB^{-1} + \lambda I).
$$
In this case, we find that for a "generic" choice of $A$, $AB^{-1}$ will have $n$ distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I clearly missed that simple trick. I accepted your answer because it was slightly earlier than the other, although both are exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you assume $A$ to be invertible, the matrix $A+\lambda B$ is invertible iff $I+\lambda A^{-1}B$ is invertible. This is the case for $\lambda=0$ and when $\lambda\neq 0$ this is equivalent to $\lambda^{-1} I + A^{-1}B$ being invertible. But this we can rewrite as $A^{-1}B - (-\lambda^{-1}) I$ being invertible.

Hence,  $A+\lambda B$ is invertible if and only if $\lambda=0$ or $-\lambda^{-1}$ is not an eigenvalue of $A^{-1} B$.

Comment: OK, so it is really obvious, and I was just being dense. Thank you.